# Integrity constraint vialations

Tags: mysql, drupal-8

I'm trying to insert data into a database in the `redirect` module (table: `redirect`) using drupal-8.

When I insert data for the first time it worked correctly, but when I insert data again, the data are inserted in database but this error arises.

```
function import_redirects($redirects) {
    foreach ($redirects as $from_url => $to_url) {
        Redirect::create([
            'redirect_source' => $from_url,
            'redirect_redirect' => 'internal:/'.$to_url,
            'language' => 'und',
            'status_code' => '301',
            'redirect_redirect__title' => NULL,
        ])->save();
    }
}
```

The error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry &#039;PBx-Sq7RCoQmsJVK-L3pYMpLiKaiyoACLU0atNt6qfE&#039; for key &#039;hash&#039;: INSERT INTO {redirect} (type, uuid, language, hash, uid,` redirect_source__path, redirect_source__query, redirect_redirect__uri, redirect_redirect__title, redirect_redirect__options, status_code, created) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11); Array
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to insert the identical entry again, it will end up with the same hash, which has to be unique.

You should check if the entry already exists, and if it doesn't, you insert it, if it does, there is no reason to insert it again.

Comment: So how to make it unique.. What should I have to do

Comment: @afridi see the second paragraph of my answer. If it already exists in the database then there is no reason to insert it again.